# Which one God have more maximum names? Krishna or Shiva?

Tags: gods, name

I read that Shiva have 1008 names and also know that Krishna have also various names. My question is which one God have more than names others?

Comment: Well, there is no competition about number of names of God. There is Shiva Sahasranama and Vishnu Sahasranama and many more names which are not mentioned in these two stotras. So, it is not possible to come to a conclusion. The names are auspicious. We have to grasp that.

Comment: I heard Lord Vishnu has 1000 names which used to teach by Narada to Prahlada(when Prahlada was living with Narada in childhood). Narada did told 999 names of Narayana but kept one name secrete and that name is Vishnu. He didn't told name Vishnu because of promise given to father of Prahlada (Hiranyakashyapa). Even though he kept name Vishnu secrete, still Prahlada got to know this name by his own(from inside). But name of incarnations are not included in those 1000 names.

Comment: Well. Shiva SahasraNaama or Krishna SahasraNaama is **not** a compilation of all possible names of any diety. There is infinite number of names of each. In fact, there are several SahasraNaama of each Shiva and Krishna(or Rama, or Vishnu, or whatever you call Him). SahasraNaama is just a kind of hymn in which there are 1000 names. But these 1000 names are not the **only limited** names. So there is no question of who has more name. As Each diety has no end of number of names.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am a follower of Shiva and sometimes when I go to temples, I see priests performing Abhisheka and chant different names of Lord Shiva. most of the time they use **Shiva Sahasra Naama** book. Sahasra means thousand, so Lord Shiva at least have 1000 names and this link listed down **1000** names [Shiva Saharsra Naama](http://www.harekrsna.de/1000Shiva.htm).

Also here is another link which listed **1000** names of lord **Vishnu**. [Lord Vishu 1000 Names](http://www.drikpanchang.com/hindu-names/gods/lord-vishnu/1008-vishnu-names.html).

Looks like both have the same number of names.